# Calculate time difference between a datetime and the current date & time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, date-format

I would like to calculate the difference between a past datetime and the current datetime with the result in `[hh]:mm` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @then datetime={ts '2014-01-23 12:34:56.789'};

SELECT LEFT(
    CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(second,
        DATEDIFF(second, @then, GETDATE()),
        {d '1900-01-01'}), 8), 5);
```

Here's what it does:

- Calculates the difference in seconds between @then and now (`GETDATE()`)
- Adds that number of seconds to 1900-01-01
- Formats the output as `hh:mm:ss`
- Returns the first five characters, i.e. `hh:mm`

Oh, and you can `REPLACE` the text "00:" with "" (nothing) if you want to hide the hour if it's less than 60 minutes:

```
SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT ....
    ...., 8), 5), '00:', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Some other approaches - I started this many hours ago and only just got back to it.

Let's first take a look at how to extract some important date part information from this data:

```
DECLARE @dt DATETIME = '2014-06-12T12:40:12', @d INT;
SELECT @d = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @dt, GETDATE());

-- at the time I ran this:
SELECT 
  @d, -- 111,027 minutes
  -- or
  @d / 60, -- 1,850 hours 
  @d % 60, -- and 27 minutes
  -- or
  @d / 1440, -- 77 days
  @d % 1440, -- and 147 minutes 
  -- or
  @d / 1440,      -- 77 Days
  @d % 1440 / 60, -- and 2 hours
  @d % 60;        -- and 27 minutes
```

Want to discard anything more than 24 hours? Ok, just take the modulo in days (1440 minutes), we just want the remainder (2 hours, 27 minutes).

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(MINUTE,@d%1440,0)),5);

-- 02:27
```

Want *all* of the hours on the left? ok:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @d/60) + ':' 
  + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @d%60), 2);

-- 1850:27
```

Need the `hh:` suppressed when it's < 1 hour? ok:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @d/60),0) + ':','') 
  + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @d%60) , 2);

-- 1850:27 in this case, but just 27 if input was 27 minutes ago
```

-- want days broken out separately? ok:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @d/1440) + ' days, '
  + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), (@d%1440/60)), 2)
  + ':' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @d%60) , 2);

-- 77 days, 02:27
```